# DOWNLOADING UBUNTU- please any help on how to download

Tags: downloads

Everytime i tried to download Ubuntu server on my windows laptop it always download as a zip file. please any help on how to download.

Comment: For me the download page gives a link that looks correct: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.2/ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso

Comment: So far he's got past the initial problem with downloading a zip file and  he's got part of the Ubuntu Server iso file to download from the download link.

Answer (score 1):

1. Visit the [official Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/server) webpage and click the button that says **Download Ubuntu Server**.
2. Select the version of Ubuntu Server and click the **Download** button.
3. The Ubuntu Server iso file can be installed via a CD, DVD or USB flash drive after it has been downloaded.

Comment: i  tried that and it download as a zip file

Comment: When I tried it in Firefox, I got a popup window that said `You have chosen to open:` the Ubuntu Server iso file and one of the options below it was *Save File*.

Comment: which browser did you download with maybe it's my browser

Comment: Are you sure it is an actual zip file and it's not just the file icon showing as a zip if your archiver app is set to open iso files as well (this is default behavior for winrar for example). Right click the saved file and choose properties and check the whole filename there in case Windows is not showing file extensions as it is by default.

Comment: i tried firefox and chrome

Comment: it's .iso but it's just 69.3mb

Comment: Then it is not downloaded completely and you should redownload it, but  your original problem should be solved.

Comment: When I tried it in Firefox, the size of the Ubuntu Server iso to be downloaded was 595MB. It tells you the size of the Ubuntu Server iso before you start downloading it. Like Sledge said, maybe you didn't wait enough time for the iso file to finish downloading.